# Get configurable product attributes in custom module?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I'm writing a custom module and Block, struggling to **get at the configurable product all attribute data that used**.

How would I set up my block class to handle this from scratch?

Attempting to use:

```
$this->_productview->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributes($this->_productview->getProduct());
```

However the page doesn't appear to ever load (will continue to try to load for ten minutes)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have access to the product you can do the following:

```
$product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributes($product);
```

Comment: I'm struggling to get access to the product, I get an error saying the method is undefined.

I'm on 2.06 and I think Magento believes my configurable product is a simple product.

Comment: @LM_Fielding Please refer to `Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/AbstractView.php` in the `getProduct()` method

Comment: Reading it now, what is the best way to get the attributes into my block?

Comment: @LM_Fielding hmmm I'm not sure at that point

Comment: I have this, but if I try to var_dump the page won't load?

{
      $this->_productview->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributes($this->_productview->getProduct());
     }

Comment: How can i get selected attribute text? i can able to get `attribute text` & `attribute id`